# How to specify Mac OSX deployment target for dependencies in Mac Catalyst when previewing?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

When trying to preview a Mac Catalyst app I run into an issue:

```
The package product 'NIOTransportServices' requires minimum platform version 10.15 for the macOS platform, but this target supports 10.10 (in target 'NIOTSHTTPServer' from project 'swift-nio-transport-services')
```

When building a preview the build system seems to not respect the deployment target set.

Obviously, as this is an iOS project with Mac as extra target the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` variable is set to `10.15`.

Building and running the app works fine.

Is there a way of manually specifying the deployment target for preview builds?

Comment: Check deployment target value in PROJECT and TARGET.

Comment: Specified to 10.15 (otherwise the app wouldn’t be able to build for Mac Catalyst), or I misunderstood your comment

Comment: What is deployement target for NIOTSHTTPServer?

Comment: Both IOS and Mac Catalyst

Comment: How are you adding NIOTransportServices in your code? I am able to run my sample iOS app with [NIOTransportServices](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-transport-services) on macOS 10.15. I have added NIOTransportServices via SPM.

Comment: I’m using SPM. Please note that thing only break when previewing a SwiftUI View in Canvas.

Comment: Also, I took NIOTransportServices as example, but all packages with deployment targets specified lower than 10.15 break the previewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out this was a bug in Xcode and is fixed since 12.0.1 and later.